# django queryset error when use len(qs) TypeError: argument must be int or float

Tags: django, sqlite

I dont know what happened with my db but now I can not len my queryset.

I can make a qs with a lot of obj with qs.SignalSma.objects.all()
But somehow I can not use len(qs) on that qs or make a loop with that qs

I am getting in this error if I try to do so.

```
    In [9]: len(qs)
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[9], line 1
    ----> 1 len(qs)
    
    File ~\OneDrive\Desktop\dev-2023\signal\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py:262, in QuerySet.__len__(self)
        261 def __len__(self):
    --> 262     self._fetch_all()
        263     return len(self._result_cache)
    
    File ~\OneDrive\Desktop\dev-2023\signal\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py:1324, in QuerySet._fetch_all(self)
       1322 def _fetch_all(self):
       1323     if self._result_cache is None:
    -> 1324         self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
       1325     if self._prefetch_related_lookups and not self._prefetch_done:
       1326         self._prefetch_related_objects()
    
    File ~\OneDrive\Desktop\dev-2023\signal\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py:68, in ModelIterable.__iter__(self)
         59 related_populators = get_related_populators(klass_info, select, db)
         60 known_related_objects = [
         61     (field, related_objs, operator.attrgetter(*[
         62         field.attname
       (...)
         66     ])) for field, related_objs in queryset._known_related_objects.items()
         67 ]
    ---> 68 for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
         69     obj = model_cls.from_db(db, init_list, row[model_fields_start:model_fields_end])
         70     for rel_populator in related_populators:
    
    File ~\OneDrive\Desktop\dev-2023\signal\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py:1122, in SQLCompiler.apply_converters(self, rows, converters)
       1120     value = row[pos]
       1121     for converter in convs:
    -> 1122         value = converter(value, expression, connection)
       1123     row[pos] = value
       1124 yield row
    
    File ~\OneDrive\Desktop\dev-2023\signal\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\operations.py:313, in DatabaseOperations.get_decimalfield_converter.<locals>.converter(value, expression, connection)
        311 def converter(value, expression, connection):
        312     if value is not None:
    --> 313         return create_decimal(value).quantize(quantize_value, context=expression.output_field.context) 
    
    TypeError: argument must be int or float
```

Any idea what is happening?? and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`QuerySet` objects have it's own counting method. Use it:

```
qs = SignalSma.objects.all()
qs.count()  # returns number of objects inside the queryset
```

Comment: This can help me to count instead of len(qs), but is not working for the  for loop.
Also my main goal is understandon why is this happening with this model and not with others

Comment: @AgustinGonzalezRibas then show that loop and how it works with other models. Error traceback is not enough.

Comment: finally I solved this error migrating to postgress, still dont know why this happened.